# Find limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Define $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x,y)=1$ if $xy=0$; $f(x,y)=0$ if $xy=otherwise$.

My professor gives this example to show a funtion with partial derivatives but not differentiable. We can pick a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ such that this sequence converges to $(0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=1$, but $lim_{(x_n,y_n)\to (0,0)}f(x_n,y_n)\not=f(0,0)$, so this function does not continuous at $(0,0)$. I want to know that how to find the limit in this case? I know that $lim_{(x_n,y_n)\to (0,0)}f(x_n,y_n)=0$, but I feel uncomfortable.

Comment: You cannot find the limit, because it does not exist as $(x,y)$ tends to $(0,0)$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an example where the limit does not exist. To see this, you can construct two sequences.

*Sequence 1*

Let $(x_n,y_n) = (1/n, 1/n)$. Then, clearly $f(x_n,y_n) = 0$ for all $n$, so the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n,y_n) = 0$ also. However...

*Sequence 2*

Let $(x_n,y_n) = (1/n, 0)$. Then instead we have $x_n y_n = 0$, so $f(x_n,y_n) = 1$ for all $n$. Thus the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n,y_n) = 1$ instead of $0$.

The fact that there are two sequences $(x_n,y_n) \to (0,0)$ with different limits under the function $f$ means that the limit of $f$ at $(0,0)$ does not exist.

*Additional*

If you are still uncomfortable, think about the following 1D example. The function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = x+1$ if $x \geq 0$ and $f(x) = x$ if $x < 0$ is obviously discontinuous at $x=0$. Another way to see this is to take the sequences $x_n = 1/n$ and $x_n = -1/n$ and to see that they have different limits under $f$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact the limit does not exists, the reason being that there are multiple limit points.

For instance for $u\to 0$ we have $f(u,0)\to 1$ and $f(e^{-\frac 1{u^2}},e^{-\frac 1{u^2}})\to 0$

The behaviour of $f(x,y)$ depends on the path followed by the sequence of points $(x,y)$.

In the above example, $x=y=\exp(-1/u^2)>0$, in particular it doesn't annulate, so $f(x,y)=0\to 0$.

On the other hand since $f(0,0)=1$ is perfectly defined, we could think about extending by continuity, but this is not possible because $f$ has no limit in $(0,0)$. So, $f$ is not even continuous at origin.